# oauth not working, for basic LinkedIn http request

Tags: ruby, oauth, linkedin-api

I have an application that: a) authenticates the user via LinkedIn, and b) authenticates access to the Linkedin API http://api.linkedin.com, through oauth. The issue is, my ouath authentication is not allowing me access to the general LinkedIn site, http://www.linkedin.com.

For example, this works:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token=AQXSs5c6R-6e_F3 ...
```

... but, this does not:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/?oauth2_access_token=AQXSs5c6R-6e_F3 ...
```

Can someone please explain the limitation here?

REF: [Another conversation I am having, on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771163/ruby-mechanize-oauth-and-linkedin-all-in-one-happy-family).

Comment: Martin, I think I have explained this pretty much. Do you need anything else?

Comment: Thanks khm, I am looking for an official answer from LinkedIn on what their oauth2_access_token gives me access to. As mentioned, I have OAuth working to make the API call, but am trying to use it for www.linkedin.com requests as well.

Comment: Welcome. I also have given this link https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2 . In step 4, they have mentioned that you can access the api.  "Once you've obtained an Access Token, you can start making authenticated API requests on behalf of the user. This is accomplished by including an "Authorization" header in your HTTP call to LinkedIn's API."

Comment: Re using the full set of LinkedIn APIs, they apparently are not available to the entrepreneur or experimental developer. I applied for access, was denied, and did not get a response to my follow up email. ... Perhaps, the Microsoft acquisition will help this. :)

Comment: Yes. They stop giving full access 1 year ago due to developer exploiting it. You have to be partner.

Comment: Is it only for large corporations, or can a startup gain access to the expanded API as well?

Comment: A startup can apply. But it must have product direction and for what purpose they need the apis. A clear product design, otherwise request might not be accepted https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Comment: I did the referenced form, and got a "standard form letter" back. Is there another route, or a follow-up contact? I think that I really have something to add to what LinkedIn offers.

Comment: I don't know. But generally a startup should have well define plan and design. And established companies get the api access easily. My older company got it but it is a bit big corporation.

Comment: khm, please note the link I added above, to s similar conversation I am having.

Comment: In response to that question, token can't work with mechanize for linkedin.  It needs cookies, sessions and all. It doesn't work on the basis of bearer token. So a user will need to enter password and username every time.

Comment: Even if you become partner,  you can't authenticate Mechanize with token.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a bit confused here about Oauth. Oauth grant you access to make request on behalf of user for a service provider (LinkedIn in your case). This is exposed as an api by service provider.

So you can make request only from https://api.linkedin.com ([Step 4](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2))

What you are trying to do is make request from site. But that's not how Oauth works. Oauth works for only providing api enabled by service provider.

Your token can make only selected requests that are exposed by LinkedIn for developer to make their applications base on their api.

Moreover, request type that you can do also depends upon the scope that you set in application configuration. **This token doesn't grant you site wide access**. Only access to those apis which are under the scope. There's no site wide scope to enable you to make any call.

Do remember to set appropriate application configuration before proceeding.

To view complete list of api calls that you can make, check [here](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin?apig_cc=1)

Comment: @Martin Sommer, I think this answer and comments cover everything you asked, so you should accept it.